# Copy-paste in IntelliJ Idea 12. What can be easier? But

Tags: intellij-idea

It turns out that for a such simple action as copy-paste I have to try very hard in IntelliJ Idea 12. I need to copy-paste many lines. I have tried many to do it by numerous ways and failed.

Other IDEs allow to do it very simply, but here it selects the area not the line(s). I even failed to paste the text because it pasted somewhat weirdly.

How can I do it exactly: copy line by line and paste?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To select multiple lines:

1. Ensure the caret is on the first column by pressing <kbd>Home</kbd> (twice if there is any indent).
2. Use <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>UP</kbd> and <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>DOWN</kbd> to select multiple lines.
3. Copy/Paste where needed. Reformatting on paste [can be adjusted](http://img16.imageshack.us/img16/2019/20130606130138.png).

Be aware of the **Expand Selection** feature (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd>) that makes it easier to select code basing on context, press it several times to expand selection.

Another way:

1. Ensure the caret is on the first column by pressing <kbd>Home</kbd> (twice if there is any indent).
2. Use <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>END</kbd> to select till the end of line, continue to hold <kbd>Shift</kbd>.
3. Press <kbd>DOWN</kbd> or <kbd>UP</kbd>. If the line it longer than the first selected, it will be selected partially. Press <kbd>END</kbd> again while still holding <kbd>Shift</kbd>, IDE will now select full lines.
4. Continue pressing <kbd>DOWN</kbd> or <kbd>UP</kbd> while holding <kbd>Shift</kbd> to expand selection on more lines.

Answer (score 2):

From your description, it sounds like you've turned on column selection mode. From the [IntelliJ IDEA help](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/selecting-text-in-the-editor.html#d322267e460):

> To toggle between the line and the column selection modes, do one of the following
>
> - On the main menu, choose **Edit** | **Column Selection Mode**.
> - On the context menu of the editor, choose **Column Selection Mode**.
> - Press <kbd>Command</kbd> <kbd>Shift</kbd> <kbd>Multiply</kbd>.
> - Keeping the middle mouse button pressed, drag the mouse.

Comment: Column Selection Mode was and is unchecked.